# Dynamic Linq Select -How to extract the results

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I have  a dynamic Linq Select statement of the form

```
var projection = result.AsQueryable().Select(string.Format("new({0},{1})",
         model.XtabRow, model.XtabColumn));
```

This works fine and produces an IQueryable of Anonymous types.

However I an unable to convert it into IEnumerable to use linq on it as AsEnumerable method seems to be missing. I had to use reflection to extract field values in the end

There must be a better way - Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: It is because the columns to be selected are not known until runtime. The select returns an IQueryable<anonymous type> and the values are correct in it.But I am unable to access the result except by using reflection.I cannot convert Iqueryable to Ienumerable<>

Comment: This is Dynamic Linq - you need Using System.Linq.Dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
var projection = result.AsQueryable().Select(string.Format("new({0},{1})",
     model.XtabRow, model.XtabColumn));

var enumerableProjection = (from dynamic p in projection select p).AsEnumerable();
```

OR

```
var projection = result.AsQueryable().Select(string.Format("new({0},{1})",
     model.XtabRow, model.XtabColumn));

var enumerableProjection = projection.Cast<dynamic>().AsEnumerable();
```